# Running Spyder from Anaconda3 Docker container

Tags: docker, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to run spyder from a docker container.

```
docker pull continuumio/anaconda3
```

then I run

```
docker run -t -i continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash
spyder
```

I get this error

```
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I could fix that by adding to the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update ##[edited]
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

However now i've got this. Any help?

```
docker run -it v1 spyder
    Update LANGUAGE_CODES (inside config/base.py) if a new translation has been added to Spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: libQt5Network.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 210, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 65, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```

---

PS: my dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
RUN mkdir /home/myhome
RUN apt-get update ##[edited]
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```